# Removing duplicate elements in a 2D Array on Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm in my second year GCSE course for Computer Science, and I've encountered a problem. I have been working on a program in Python that allows the user to enter a symbol and letter pair to try and decode an encoded message.

The letters and symbols will be saved in a 2D Array in the format `[[letter, symbol][letter,symbol]]`. My problem is, I can't find a way to flag up any occurrences when the user has entered a letter or symbol twice.

I have been tinkering around with it for a while now, and this is my best solution:

```
def DUPLICATE(decodeArray):
    seen = set()
    for item in decodeArray:
        t = tuple(item)
        print(t)
        if t not in seen:
            newList.append(item)
            seen.add(t)
            print(seen)
```

Unfortunately, all this does is notices if an entire sub-array (not sure of the correct word) has been duplicated, i.e `[[a,b][c,d][a,b]]`.
This uses another array called `newList` and if it spots a duplicate sub-array, it won't include it.

I've attempted myself and used this website to look for a way, but I can't find one anywhere. Can somebody help?

Comment: Why just use two `seen` sets? One for letters and one for symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You have already noticed, that it appends a whole array. What you need to do then is just iterate over that one, along the lines of:

```
(...)
for row in decodeArray:
    for column in row:
(...)
```